# Compare value difference on a rolling basis

Tags: excel

Trying to compare the difference in two values on a rolling basis. Specifically, I want to compare 10-year treasury yields 6 months and one year into the future.

For example, if:

Date:
01/01/2017 2.40
07/01/2017 2.70
01/01/2018 2.90

Then:

07/01/2017 0.30
01/01/2018 0.50

Looking to compare this on treasury yields for the last 10 years. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what the question is. Do you want to project the value into the future, so you'd be interested in using some form of regression analysis?
Or is it the problem in how to populate the data into Excel? If this is it please indicate what format is the data originally?

Comment: I didn't know I could add a comment. You didn't need to vote me down for trying to help.

Comment: My apologies. I am still getting the hang of it.